# downloading csv data from google chart jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Sorry I'm new with this.

I have a html with jquery where I read a csv file with 10 columns. I plot only two of those in my line chart. Now I would like to be able to download those two columns in a new csv file. I cant manage to "link" my data to the script below.

This is what I have done so far:

```
function draw() {
 drawToolbar();
}

function drawToolbar() {
 var components = [
  {type: 'csv', datasource: ('data')} //<--here is the problem
 ];
 var container = document.getElementById('toolbar_div');
 google.visualization.drawToolbar(container, components);
};

google.setOnLoadCallback(draw);
```

EDIT: link to the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aldin/4x4H4/

Comment: If you could use jsFiddle to provide a working (or non-working) example of what you're trying to do, it'll be easier for us to figure it out and help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aldin/4x4H4/

Comment: Where are you hosting jquery-csv? I want to add it to the fiddle.

Comment: It seems to be working ok for me... I had to add in some markup for the chart_title element, and had to hard code the csv, b/c of cross-domain restrictions. You can see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/4x4H4/2/

Comment: I suspect your issue is probably with either: 1) The ajax call to fetch the csv or 2) not loading either the jquery-csv or google library correctly.